# Push Characters of a String into a stack (RISC-V ISA, RV64I)

Tags: assembly, riscv

I have an assignment where I prompt for a word input. Then the characters of the word is stored in a stack and from there I would have to determine whether the word is a palindrome.

I was wondering how do I push a letter into the stack? This is just the beginning of my code. Once I figure out how to push each letter of the word, I should be good to go:

```
s1: DC  "Enter string:"

STACK:  EQU 0x100000
    lui sp, STACK >> 12

    addi    x5, x0, s1
    ecall   x1, x5, 4;
    ecall   x5, x0, 8;
```

Comment: You don't need to use the callstack or push/pop to check for palindromes, just get a pointers to the start and end, and walk them towards each other until they cross.  Using temporary storage in memory (especially 1 word per byte) is very inefficient.  But if you insist, just zero-extend a byte into a full register and then push/pop that like normal.

Comment: What kind of RISC-V assembler do you use? These DC/EQU directives look unfamiliar.